# Are there any cons of using Swift/Kotlin for Flutter platform plugins?

Tags: flutter

Most of Flutter platform plugins are written in Obj-C/Java. Are there any technical cons like performance, app size of using Swift/Kotlin over it?

Answer (score 1):

The latest flutter plugins for Intellij and VS Code by default set Swift and Kotlin as the platform specific languages.

It means Google suggests for all developers to prefer Swift/Kotlin instead of Obj-C/Java for their platform specific code moving forward.